# How to get polygon properties when a marker is placed on it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps.js

Using google map Drawing Manager user draws the polygon .I want to get polygon properties(title,paths,..) when a marker(marker from drawing manager) is placed on it. Here I want to know how to get the properties of the polygon(title, paths) and then like to it in a variable.

code :

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>Get Latitude and Longitude Coordinates of a Polygon - Google Maps API v3</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&libraries=drawing&sensor=true"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="gmaps.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mapHeight = '400px';
    $('#map-canvas').css('height', mapHeight);
    mymap = new GMaps({
        div: '#map-canvas',
        lat: 47.53187912201915,
        lng: 7.705222390807307,
        zoom: 20,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });
       map = mymap.map;
map_drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: null,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
                drawingModes: [
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
                ]
            },
            //drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            markerOptions: {
                draggable: true,
            },

            polylineOptions: {
                editable: true
            },
            map: map
         });

      });  

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 350px; width: auto;">
</div>
<div id="info" style="position: absolute; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It would be fine to show a alert message of the polygon properties When I place the marker on it. Hope There will be possible for this.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd29L76L/)

Comment: What is the purpose of "dropping" a marker on the polygon?  Why not just a [click handler that displays the information in an infowindow](http://jsfiddle.net/bd29L76L/1/)?

Comment: @@geocodezip: main purpose of dropping a marker on polygon is to save the marker with the polygon properties. Mainly I want to store with polygon name and id

Comment: @@geocodezip: Also is there any way to check whether the marker inside polygon or not.

Comment: [containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation)

Comment: @@geocodezip: thanks for the sample link. It has code to check inside polygon or not when map is clicked. But it doesnt work for marker click/drop. Can you please check it.

Comment: @@geocodezip: I updated my post Please have a look at it  and code in http://jsfiddle.net/16xbta3h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to declare an array holding every polygon that the user draws and then, when the user adds a marker, you would need to iterate over your polygonarray until you find one that contains the marker. This is done by adding listeners to Drawingmanager's polygoncomplete and markercomplete events.

```
var polygonArray=[];

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    polygonArray.push(polygon);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'markercomplete', function (marker) {
    polygonArray.forEach(function(polygon) {
        if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.getPosition(), polygon)) {
            console.log('Marker added inside polygon',polygon);
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: I was missing a closing parenthesis after containsLocation

See it working at: http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/zfvyou0b/

Comment: @@amenadiel: your code seems not working as expected. I mean cant able to determine the point inside polygon though it is assigned as you said.Can you please tell me the exact code? if possile Put it in jsfiddle

Comment: @@amenadiel: Please look the link http://jsfiddle.net/o8rt0rqL/3/  and you can see that I commented few lines. If I uncomment it, then nothing works. I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: Edited my answer. See it working at See it working at: http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/zfvyou0b/