# Get Array of all points of Polygon - Google Maps Drawing Tool API-3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

i am using Google Drawing tools for drawing polygon/rectangle on google maps, now i need to show markers that falls inside the drawn polygon and for that i am using geometry.poly.containsLocation method which takes a point(latLng) and an array of polygon points. if i use maps.polygon I can get polygon points via poly.getPath() but because i am using [Google Drawing tools](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools) which uses maps.drawing.DrawingManager/google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON so not sure how to find points here. Thanks

```
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
  drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
  drawingControl: true,
  drawingControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
    drawingModes: [
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
    ]
  },
  markerOptions: {
    icon: 'images/car-icon.png'
  },
  circleOptions: {
    fillColor: '#ffff00',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    clickable: false,
    editable: true,
    zIndex: 1
  },
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#BCDCF9',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeColor:'#57ACF9',
    clickable: false,
    editable: false,
    zIndex: 1
  }
});
console.log(drawingManager)
drawingManager.setMap(map)
```

Comment: Related question: [How to get polygon properties when a marker is placed on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140181/how-to-get-polygon-properties-when-a-marker-is-placed-on-it)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    // assuming you want the points in a div with id="info"
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "polygon points:" + "<br>";
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
    }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qe68usv3/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var polygonArray = [];

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    },
    /* not useful on jsfiddle
    markerOptions: {
      icon: 'images/car-icon.png'
    }, */
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    },
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: '#BCDCF9',
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: '#57ACF9',
      clickable: false,
      editable: false,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  console.log(drawingManager)
  drawingManager.setMap(map)

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "polygon points:" + "<br>";
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
    }
    polygonArray.push(polygon);
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style=" border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: I prefer functional approach more than manual looping. `polygon.getPath().forEach((point) => doSomething(point))` looked better to me.

Answer (score 10):

A slightly different solution than what [geocodezip proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30670500), but using the same API calls:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    var path = polygon.getPath()
    var coordinates = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < path.length ; i++) {
      coordinates.push({
        lat: path.getAt(i).lat(),
        lng: path.getAt(i).lng()
      });
    }
    console.log(coordinates);
});
```

Comment: upvoted, but second part is a bit hardcoded. You can get array of type `Array<LatLng>` by `array= path.getArray()`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the `DrawingManager` will fire events when the user finishes drawing something and the event handler will receive a normal `google.maps.Polygon`, `google.maps.Rectangle`, and so on. I would try that.

[Here's a documentation link.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#events_301)