# Google Maps Drawing Manager get position of clicked point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the `Google Maps Drawing Manager` to click different points to draw a polygon. Using this example: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          markerOptions: {
            draggable: true
          },
          polylineOptions: {
            editable: true
          },
          rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
          circleOptions: polyOptions,
          polygonOptions: polyOptions,
          map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
            if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
            console.log('Overlay complete!!!');
            // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
            // mouses down on it.
            var newShape = e.overlay;
            newShape.type = e.type;
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
              setSelection(newShape);
            });

            setSelection(newShape);
          }
        });

        // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
        // map is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);
```

**What I would like to do is get a `click` event every time I click my mouse to create a point on the map, and I would like to get the `lat` and `lon` of that clicked point on the map. Is this possible?**

Or, alternately, could I export all of the points lat and lon after the polygon is created?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Array of all points of Polygon - Google Maps Drawing Tool API-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670080/get-array-of-all-points-of-polygon-google-maps-drawing-tool-api-3)

Comment: The drawing manager takes over the click event on the map, so you wont be able to get the coordinates through the API until the polygon is complete.

Comment: That is fine with me.

Comment: You can get the coordinates, just not from the map, the answers below that use the domListener on the map div work just fine-

Answer (score 1):

Yes possible, please see below

```
var lat, lng; //global variables

function initialize() {
    ...
    ...


    //add these lines to capture latitude and longitude
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('map'), 'mousemove', function(event) {

        var ll = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(
                            new google.maps.Point(event.clientX, event.clientY));

        lat = ll.lat();
        lng = ll.lng();

        console.log(ll.lng() +", "+ll.lat());

    }); 
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now use these latitude (lat) and longitude (lng) variables in your click event or elsewhere :)

Comment: This is the correct answer, except you'll likely want the "click" event and not mousemove, and to make sure you're getting the right map coordinates from the div clientX/Y, see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219346/how-to-convert-from-x-y-screen-coordinates-to-latlng-google-maps

Comment: Who is `overlay` from `overlay.getProjection()...`?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript within the browser is event `drive`, javascript responds to interactions by generating events and expects a program to `listen` to interesting events. User events such as "click" mouse events are propagated from the DOM to the Google Maps JavaScript API.

In certain events will register JavaScript event listeners for those events and execute code when those events are received by calling `addListener()` to register event handlers on the object.

Here's a sample code snippet how to implement `click` event listener:

```
function initMap() {
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
});

// We add a DOM event here to show an alert if the DIV containing the
// map is clicked.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapDiv, 'click', function() {
window.alert('Map was clicked!');
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to just get all of the coordinates after the shape was completed:

```
var vertices = selectedShape.getPath();
for (var i =0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
    var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
    xy.lat();// Latitude
    xy.lng();// Longitude
 }
```

Comment: This user is requesting to get the coordinates before the new overlay is returned